# Bounding Box of the Line Arrangement in O(n log n) time

Tags: algorithm, geometry, line, bounding-box

I want to compute the bounding box of a line arrangement (with no parallel lines). The bounding box should contain all intersections of the line arrangement.

I have done some research and found several times that computing the bounding box should be possible in O(n log n) time. Unfortunately I was not able to find the source of this claim.

I tried to come up with an algorithm that solves this problem in O(n log n) time but was not able so far. I tried to use duality to compute the envelopes but unfortunately the envelopes do not always contain the lowest and highest intersection.

I would appreciate if someone know where to find such an algorithm or how it works.

Comment: Segments or infinite lines?

Comment: `no parallel lines` (sort of) spells infinite, *unless* it was Sloppish for *no line parallel to one of the plain axes*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to do it in O(n log n) time. We don't have to check every intersection, we just need to find the ones with highest/lowest x and y-coordinate.

Here's what I came up with. I think we are in the same lecture, and this is pretty much exactly what I am going to hand in, so please don't just copy paste it, if you want to use this solution.

Algorithm for left bound:

1) Make lines into points according to point-line duality l:y = mx + c => l* = (m, -c). O(n)

2) Order them by x-coordinate. O(n log n)

3) Save line of first two points as line with lowest slope. O(1)

4) Go through points and if a line of two points P[i] and P[i+1] has lower slope than previously saved lowest slope, save that line as line with lowest slope. O(n)

5) Make the line into a point, using duality again. O(1)

6) Return x-coordinate of that point as left bound. O(1)

The line with the lowest slope represents the intersection point with the lowest x-coordinate. Right bound works the same but with highest slope. In order to get an algorithm for upper and lower bound we can change the duality to l:y = mx + c => l* = (-c, m) (basically turning the plane 90 degrees) in order to be able to determine the lowest and highest intersection points by looking at the slopes as well.

We don't have to look at all intersection points of lines in order to find the steepest slope, looking at lines that are next to each other according to x-coordinate is enough.

Comment: `line with the lowest slope represents the intersection point with the lowest x-coordinate` - nice. Can you please argue *why* only "dual neighbours in *x*" ("original neighbours in slope") need to be considered?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... you want me to explain, why I only look at points that are next to each other in the list sorted by x-coordinate instead of every combination of two points?

Comment: @greybeard Consider two lines A and B with slope(A) < slope(B) and intersection p. A third line X with slope(A) < slope(X) < slope(B) will either have two intersections to the right and left of p, or the new intersections will be equal to p. In both cases we can ignore p.

Comment: How can you make sure that the lowest-slope line is formed by two consecutive points in the dual form? Why it is not possible that a lowest-slope line is formed by P[i], P[i+2], for instance?

Comment: @X.Arthur Suppose we have a slope AB between two points A, B. Now try putting another point X between them and inspect the slopes AX and XB. You'll see that one of AX and XB will always be more steep and the other one less steep than AB (except if X is exactly on AB). You can easily try all cases, putting X above both A and B, putting X above AB but below the higher point etc. Since there is no way to place an X so that AB remains the steepest slope, we can conclude that the steepest slopes are always between two adjacent points.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with what [PelicanFive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6881794/pelicanfive) said, as you still need to examine all different pairs to find the lowest-slope lines.

My method of dealing with this question is (let's take the leftmost and rightmost intersection for instance) to use a vertical line from very far on the left and very far from the right to sweep towards the intersections.

In the very far distance, this vertical line will intersect with all these lines in a sequence from top to bottom, record this sequence.

Notice that if this verticle line passes some intersection vertex, the sequence will change.

In a decision tree model, the number of steps to find the first intersection vertex is O(log n), and each check will take O(n).

Thus, the total runtime is O(n log n).

It is the same for top-most and bottom-most vertices.